# How to remove xml parent tag using XML DOM javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmldom

I am working on replace xml node.  I have problem in remove parent node with inner node itself.

I want to remove parent node with few inner node and retain some other inner nodes.

The Source of the xml string:

```
 <root>
 ***<bPoint id="1" >
       <bLabel>
            <text></text>
       </bLabel>
       <content src="p112" />***
       <bPoint id="2">
           <bLabel>
               <text>xxx</text>
           </bLabel>
           <content src="p1123" />
       </bPoint>
 ***</bPoint>***
     <bPoint id="bPoint-2" >
         <bLabel>
             <text>xxx</text>
         </bLabel>
           <content src="p1123" />        
    </bPoint>
 </root>
```

My Output will be

```
<root>
<bPoint id="2">
     <bLabel>
        <text>xxx</text>
     </bLabel>
      <content src="p1123" />
 </bPoint>
<bPoint id="bPoint-2" >
   <bLabel>
         <text>xxx</text>
   </bLabel>
   <content src="p1123" />         
</bPoint>
</root>
```

Any one assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) method on the parent node of the node you want to replace.

so you would want to do a replaceChild on root passing in your bPoint with id 2 as the first argument and bPoint with id 1 as the second

```
rootNode.replaceChild(bPoint2,bPoint1);
```

Demo

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><root><bPoint id="1"><bLabel><text></text></bLabel><content src="p112" /><bPoint id="2"><bLabel><text>xxx</text></bLabel><content src="p1123" /></bPoint></bPoint><bPoint id="bPoint-2" ><bLabel><text>xxx</text></bLabel><content src="p1123" /></bPoint></root>'

//Create xml parser and parse to XMLDocument
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

//Get "root" node
var rootNode = xmldoc.querySelector("root");

//Would use id selectors but number ids are invalid selectors
var bPoint1 = xmldoc.querySelector("bPoint");
var bPoint2 = bPoint1.querySelector("bPoint");

//Replace bPoint 1 with bPoint2
rootNode.replaceChild(bPoint2,bPoint1);

//Get the new xml string
var newXml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(xmldoc);

console.log(xmldoc);
document.body.innerText = newXml;
```

Comment: If i have more bPoint inside, How to replace multiple bPoint into single bPoint?

Comment: The question was tagged with node.js. So what package does support `xmldoc.querySelector`?